# Regex for this {{mike}} {{michael}} {{jordan}}

Tags: regex, regex-group

My String is -> {{mike}} {{michael}} {{jordan}}

Give me result like this

- group 1 -> mike
- group 2 -> michael
- group 3 -> jordan

Comment: which programming language are you using ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Start from here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can go for this

`\{\{(\w+)\}\}`

It captures all the characters inside the double braces (without spaces, if you need space you can use `[\w\s]*` inside the braces)